# find a particular text is present or not inside an element using xpath or ruby capybara code

Tags: xpath, capybara

Iam working with test automation .for that am using ruby capybara to write test scripts.Using

Ruby cabybara code i want to check a text is present is not inside dev element

how can i possible?

```
<div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="orderCompleteNoEmailLabel">
            Your order is placed, but one more step is needed to complete it.
        </h3>  

</div>
```

Here i want to check the text Your order is placed, but one more step is needed to complete it. is present or not.

Answer (score 1):

the following xpath should return true if the text contains the given string

```
//h3[contains(., "Your order is placed")]=true()
```

Comment: getting `                 ^
Confirmation_Page.rb:80: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_e
nd
    h3[contains(., "Your order is placed")]=true()`